# Can I use GitHub as my mobile app's data store?

Tags: ios, legal, github, mobile, storage

Given a relatively simple mobile app that consumes semi-static (infrequently updated by hand) data, is it a good idea to simply store said data in a public GitHub repo, in form of a structured collection of JSON files?

That data contains nothing sensitive or secret (thus there is no risk in making it public) and it doesn't need to be frequently refetched. The number of those JSON files is relatively large though, and it is advantageous to be able to tweak or add new files easily and quickly.

All of this makes storing the data on GitHub sound like a viable option. However:

- Does this violate any terms of service, on either GitHub's or Apple's side of things (assuming the app is for iOS)?
- Does this have serious scalability problems that make the idea not feasible beyond a simple experiment? The data won't be requested by the app very often, but the GitHub repo is still likely to receive a heavier than normal load, if the number of users grows.
- Are there any other issues with this?

Comment: I think this is bad idea.  That is all.

Comment: As an alternative you might want to look at using Amazon S3, but of course you have to pay for that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm reading the [Term of Service](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/) of the site and i think that you can use GitHub to host your JSON file.

But pay attention to this point:

> If your bandwidth usage significantly exceeds the average bandwidth usage (as determined solely by GitHub) of other GitHub customers, we reserve the right to immediately disable your account or throttle your file hosting until you can reduce your bandwidth consumption.

And I don't know the use you will made of your data but remember that:

> You may not use the Service for any illegal or unauthorized purpose. You must not, in the use of the Service, violate any laws in your jurisdiction (including but not limited to copyright or trademark laws).

[Here](https://github.com/contact) you can find a contact page you can use to ask information via email, could be a good idea to ask before upload your files. ;-)

**EDIT**
I've made some research and I've found that there are a lot of site like [Myjson](http://myjson.com/) or [JSON Blob](https://jsonblob.com/) you can use to store JSON files, I hope it helps.

Comment: For overloading issue, there is http://rawgit.com.